# Google App Script - Script to write in cells according to the day of the week

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to add this section to my Google app script.
I want to add a script that changes the cell to write into, according to the day of the week.
For example:

```
If day=monday then write in cell S1
If day=tuesday then write in cell T1
If day=wednsday then write in cell U1
```

ecc.

Do you know how can i achieve this result?
Thanks!

EDIT: This works for me!

```
    if (total != 'error') {
    if(new Date().getDay() === 0){
       sh3.getRange('S'+counter).setValue(total);
    } else if(new Date().getDay() === 1){
       sh3.getRange('T'+counter).setValue(total);
    } else if(new Date().getDay() === 2){
       sh3.getRange('U'+counter).setValue(total);
    } else if(new Date().getDay() === 3){
       sh3.getRange('V'+counter).setValue(total);
    } else if(new Date().getDay() === 4){
       sh3.getRange('W'+counter).setValue(total);
    } else if(new Date().getDay() === 5){
       sh3.getRange('X'+counter).setValue(total);
    } else if(new Date().getDay() === 6){
       sh3.getRange('Y'+counter).setValue(total);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: I'm doing it right now actually :)

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, you can get the day of the week (numeric index) using `new Date().getDay()` method.
The next part is to get a reference to the target cell on the spreadsheet using `sheet.getRange()` method.

I would recommend to go through the following resources to understand how the solution works:

1. [getDay() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)
2. [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
3. [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

#### Solution:

The following code will,

- On Sunday, write the string "test" to cell S1,
- On Monday, write the string "test" to cell S2 and so on.

```js
const spreadsheetId = "...";
const sheetName = "Sheet1";
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
const today = new Date().getDay();
const cell = sheet.getRange(`S${today+1}`)
cell.setValue("test");
```

If you want to skip Sunday and write to S1 on Monday, you need to modify it

```js
if (today > 0) {
  const cell = sheet.getRange(`S${today}`)
  cell.setValue("test");
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i wrote the wrong example since the correct sequence to write my function is S1, T1, U1, ecc... not S1, S2, S3.
I'm trying another way with else if and getDay()==="monday"

Comment: No problem :) Just a note that `getDay()` returns a number (0-6).

Comment: I tryed some solutions but i don't know why it doesn't work :<

Comment: ok now it works ^^

Answer (score 0):

#### Use getDay() method of Date() object like this:

```
sheet.getRange(1, new Date().getDay() + 19).setValue()
```